# How do I remove sticky glue from a surface using baking soda after removing peel and stick tiles?

Tags: flooring

I'm removing "peel and stick" tile from ceramic tile and need to know how your reader used baking soda to remove the sticky glue from the surface after the tile was removed.

Comment: If you have more than just one tile or two, you'll spend ages scrubbing it off with soda... Better get a dedicated product, like Goo Gone (the solvent-based, stronger type), wear gloves and have proper ventilation.

Comment: "Your reader"? Who is that?

Answer (score 1):

The tiles I removed left very little "glue", meaning I didn't see rows of it on the floor. It was however very tacky. I used a sifter and sprinkled baking soda over the entire area, immediately the tackiness was gone. It was about a 10x12 area. It worked great for me but I do think it would depend on the amount of glue left on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I am using turps and wire wool it is working very well but you need good ventilation. I will wash though after with soapy water maybe twice as turps is very oily. helen

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0):

I use a heat gun and a 6in spatula to pull up the tiles that works very fast and easy next I take baking soda and spread it on the stickiness left on the underlayment and brush it in real hard with a hard bristle brush and that gets rid of the sticky residue.

Answer (score 0):

I used baby powder. Just sprinkle it on the sticky floor and then let sit for a few minutes and go back and sweep up the baby powder and that's it.